# Adding Ground or Earth to the shielded cable

Tags: i2c, grounding, shielding, earth

[image]

I am using 8 core shielded cable to transfer I2C signal along with analog sensor data. We have connected earth to the shied cable, we have option to connect DC ground also. Everywhere I have read shied should be connected to ground. If we have earth line should we connect it to shield. We have connected device chassis to the earth.

Comment: Ask yourself this - why does your cable have a shield? The answer will point to the correct answer choice in your question.

Comment: What kind of 8 core shielded cable it is? Twisted pair like CAT5, or normal cable? Are you sure I2C has a chance of working through it?